# MongoDB remove() function deletes documents but retains indexes

Tags: mongodb, delete

I have came across in one of my readings that remove() function will delete the documents without any changes to the existing indexes.

for instance: "db.users.remove() - This will remove all of the documents in the users collection. This doesn’t actually remove the collection, and **any indexes created on it will still exist.**"

I would like to understand why the indexes are retained when the actual referenced data is removed / deleted in that specific collection? is there any specific use case?

Thank you

Comment: Are you wondering about index _keys_ not being removed, or the index _definition_ not being removed? The difference is crucial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [db.collection.remove()](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.remove/) command is used to remove data from a collection. As such, documents will be removed from the collection and the indexes on the collection will be updated to no longer reference the removed documents.

Remove can be used in such a way to only remove a subset of data. [From the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.remove/#remove-all-documents-that-match-a-condition):

```
db.products.remove( { qty: { $gt: 20 } } )
```

For example, you may want to remove a subset of data but retain the existing indexes to continue access the remaining data according to the existing access patterns.

This command contrasts from the [db.collection.drop()](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.drop/#db.collection.drop) command, which removes the entire collection along with its indexes.

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB v3.6+ (mine was v3.6.8), after a `db.products.remove()` operation, you can [re-create the index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.reIndex/) by issuing a:

```
db.products.reIndex()
```

otherwise tools like [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/compass) may report an open collection to be empty if you removed several documents from the collection using another tool like the `mongo` CLI.